# Collision detection on a map

Tags: canvas, collision-detection, collision

Character doesn't move when i press 2 bottons near collision block

Hello. I'm making a game but I'm stuck with collision detection, everything works almost as I need it but the problem is that when I press 2 buttons at the same time and approach(touch) a collision block, the character doesn't move until I stop pressing one of the buttons nad it happens only with Y, help me please find a problem

```
update(){

    this.sides.right = this.position.x + this.width;
    this.sides.bottom = this.position.y + this.height;
   
    let moving = true;

    if ((keys['ArrowRight'] || keys['KeyD']) && this.sides.right < canvas.width){
        for (let i= 0; i < boundaries.length; i++ ){
            const boundary = boundaries[i];
            if (rectangularCollision({
                rectangle1: player,
                rectangle2: {...boundary, position:{
                        x: boundary.position.x - 6,
                        y: boundary.position.y,
                    }},
            })){
                console.log("collision1")
                moving = false;
                break
            }
        }
        if (moving)
            this.position.x += this.speed.sx;
        console.log("D")

    } else if ((keys['ArrowLeft'] || keys['KeyA']) && this.position.x > 0){
        for (let i= 0; i < boundaries.length; i++ ){
            const boundary = boundaries[i];
            if (rectangularCollision({
                rectangle1: player,
                rectangle2: {...boundary, position:{
                        x: boundary.position.x + 6,
                        y: boundary.position.y,
                    }},
            })){
                console.log("collision2")
                moving = false;
                break
            }
        }
        if (moving)
            this.position.x -= this.speed.sx;
        console.log("A")
    }

    if ((keys['ArrowDown'] || keys['KeyS']) && this.sides.bottom < canvas.height ) {
        for (let i= 0; i < boundaries.length; i++ ){
            const boundary = boundaries[i];
            if (rectangularCollision({
                rectangle1: player,
                rectangle2: {...boundary, position:{
                        x: boundary.position.x,
                        y: boundary.position.y - 5,
                    }},
            })){
                console.log("collision3")
                moving = false;
                break
            }
        }
        if (moving)
            this.position.y += this.speed.sy;
            console.log("S")

    } else if ((keys['ArrowUp'] || keys['KeyW']) && this.position.y > 0) {
        for (let i= 0; i < boundaries.length; i++ ){
            const boundary = boundaries[i];
            if (rectangularCollision({
                rectangle1: player,
                rectangle2: {...boundary, position:{
                        x: boundary.position.x,
                        y: boundary.position.y + 5,
                    }},
            })){
                console.log("collision4")
                moving = false;
                break
            }
        }
        if (moving)
            this.position.y -= this.speed.sy;
            console.log("W")
    }

const collisionRoom1 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 2684354563, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2684354563, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

function rectangularCollision({rectangle1, rectangle2}){
return (
rectangle1.position.x + rectangle1.width >= rectangle2.position.x &&
rectangle1.position.x <= rectangle2.position.x + rectangle2.width &&
rectangle1.position.y  <= rectangle2.position.y + rectangle2.height &&
rectangle1.position.y + rectangle1.height >= rectangle2.position.y
)
}

function animation() {
window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);

```
level1.draw();

// collision /////////////////////
boundaries.forEach(boundary =>{
    boundary.draw()
})
//////////////////////////////////

player.draw();
player.update();
```

}

animation();